# How can I have same value in first column but only if second column is different

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table 'lessons' in SQL Server

```
LessonId | Name | SectionId | Description
```

Can I create a unique constraint on `Name` and `SectionId`?

- `Name` can be same but only if `SectionId` is different
- `SectionId` is a foreign key

Example:

```
| Name      | SectionId |
+-----------+-----------+
| Basics    | 1         |
| Basics    | 2         |
| Lesson 2  | 1         |
```

Thank you

Comment: `alter table lessons add constraint unq_lessons_name_sectionid UNIQUE (name, sectionid);`

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a unique constraint on two column:

```
alter table lessons add constraint unq_ lessons_name_sectionid on (name, sectionid);
```

You can also do this using a unique index.